# how can the world to map transform be calculated

Tags: transform, mapping, world

Given the origin of the map in lat,lon, yaw, pitch and roll how can one calculate the transform from world to map?

Here are the steps I have done:

calculate the ENU to ECEF transform

```
# Calculate the ENU to ECEF transform given lat lon
sl = np.sin(rad(lon))
sp = np.sin(rad(lat))
cl = np.cos(rad(lon))
cp = np.cos(rad(lat))

# Rotation Variables Naming Convension:
# R_FRAME1_FRAME2: Rotation that goes from Frame1 to Frame2

R_ENU_ECEF = np.array([[-sl, -sp*cl, cp*cl],
                       [ cl, -sp*sl, cp*sl],
                       [  0,     cp,    sp]])
```

Calculate the MAP to ENU transform given the MAP origin pose

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation

R_MAP_ENU = Rotation.from_euler('xyz', [-origin_yaw, -origin_pitch, -origin_roll]).as_matrix()
```

Calculate the MAP to ECEF transform given the above
R_MAP_ECEF = R_MAP_ENU @ R_ENU_ECEF

```
Rotation.from_matrix(R_MAP_ECEF).as_euler('xyz')
```

But I am not getting the correct values.

My goal is to use the result to output a static world to map transform